# How to TakeOff a Quadcopter steadly in stabilized mode with using gazebo and sitl?

Tags: python, mavlink

In our project we want to design a software about indoor autonomous drone. I want to test my softares on gazebo so I use sitl for that. But when I give takeoff command in stabilize mode with using rc_channels_override message , the drone is moving unsteadly and somersaults. What should I do to takeoff and control the drone steadly without using GPS data?

You can find the code below;

```
from pymavlink import mavutil
import sys
import time
autotune_bool = False

def mod_change(master , mode_name): #this function changes fligth mode of the UAV.

if mode_name not in master.mode_mapping():
    print('Unknown mode : {}'.format(mode_name))
    print('Try:', list(master.mode_mapping().keys()))
    sys.exit(1)



mode_id = master.mode_mapping()[mode_name]
master.mav.set_mode_send(
    master.target_system,
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_MODE_FLAG_CUSTOM_MODE_ENABLED,
    mode_id)
def arming_motors():

the_connection.mav.command_long_send(the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component,
                                 mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_COMPONENT_ARM_DISARM, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
def autotune_axis():

the_connection.mav.command_long_send(the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component,
                                 mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_DO_AUTOTUNE_ENABLE, 1, 3 , 0 , 0,0,0,0,0)
the_connection.mav.command_long_send(the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component,
                                 mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_DO_AUTOTUNE_ENABLE, 1, 1 , 0 , 0,0,0,0,0)
the_connection.mav.command_long_send(the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component,
                                 mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_DO_AUTOTUNE_ENABLE, 1, 2 , 0 , 0,0,0,0,0)
def set_rc_channel_pwm(master , id, pwm=1500):

if id < 1:
    print("Channel does not exist.")
    return
#http://mavlink.org/messages/common#RC_CHANNELS_OVERRIDE
if id < 9:
    rc_channel_values = [65535 for _ in range(8)]
    rc_channel_values[id - 1] = pwm
    rc_channel_values[4] = 1900
    master.mav.rc_channels_override_send(
        master.target_system,                # target_system
        master.target_component,             # target_component
        *rc_channel_values)                  # RC channel list, in microseconds.
the_connection = mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:localhost:5762')
the_connection.wait_heartbeat()

mod_change(the_connection , 'STABILIZE')

time.sleep(2)

#autotune_axis()

time.sleep(3)
arming_motors()
time.sleep(2)

msg = the_connection.recv_match(type='COMMAND_ACK', blocking=True)
print(msg)

bas_time = time.time()

while True:

code_time = time.time()

if code_time - bas_time <= 2.0:
    set_rc_channel_pwm(the_connection , 3, 1525)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `MAV_MODE_FLAG_CUSTOM_MODE_ENABLED` and set to `'GUIDED'` we can send the command `MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF` here:

```
mode = 'GUIDED'
mode_id = the_connection.mode_mapping()[mode]
the_connection.mav.set_mode_send(
    the_connection.target_system,
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_MODE_FLAG_CUSTOM_MODE_ENABLED,
    mode_id)
the_connection.mav.command_long_send(the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component,
                                     mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. But this function is a DroneKit function. I do not want to use DroneKit. I want to have a code with only using mavlink commands.

Comment: Gotcha, I edited the answer to use mavlink's functions instead.